# Updating variables through Uart ISR without breaking allocation

Tags: c, arm, embedded

My incoming values are inside data packages.I have to read the package and afterwards use this package to extract real values.I used some bitwise operations and Consistive Byte Stuffing Algoritm to form a package.

In the receiving side when it detects there is an incoming byte over Uart ,MCU will run ISR. Read package. Send it to decoder function which returns array of decoded values.

Since i am returning an array ,i had to use *malloc* and i have to use *free(xxx)* function.I learned that using *free()* inside of ISR is bad idea. So i edited my code in a certain way and put free(xxx) inside of main loop.

Here you see my interrupt handler function which runs after every succesfull read.

```
    void HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart)  
{

//{2,32,2,140,3,168,100,3,1,16,0} this is an example package.End byte is always 0 and there is no other possible occurrence of 0 in 1 package thanks to the COBS algoritm

count_dooku++; // this variable counts how many interrupt has occurred. Mostly usefull For debuging.  If i use free() inside of this function count_dooku stops at 22 which means after reading 2 packages it stopped. If there is no free() interrupts keep working as they should 

if (huart->Instance == USART1)  //current UART 
    {

    int a=0;

   if (Rx_indx==0) {for (int i=0;i<30;i++) Rx_Buffer[i]=0;}   //clear Rx_Buffer before receiving new data 

    if (Rx_data[0]!=a) //if received data different from  package end byte 0 //
        {
        Transfer_cplt=0;// reset Transfer_cplt value to 0 since we are receiving new package 

        Rx_Buffer[Rx_indx++]=Rx_data[0];    //add data to Rx_Buffer
        }
    else            //if received data = 0 which means end of the package
        {

       //now transfer completed, data is ready to read
                 if (Rx_indx==10)  //check the lenght of the package if true continue 
                 {
                    for( int i=0; i < 11; i++ ){
                    un_decoded_data[i]=  *( Rx_Buffer + i ) ; 
                    }  copy package values from buffer to another array.

                        Transfer_cplt=1;  // mission completed. Pakage is in "un_decoded_data"                          
                  }
                 Rx_indx=0;  //reset index counter for new data


          }


    }

 HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart1, Rx_data, 1);   //activate UART receive interrupt every time

   }
```

Here is my main loop :

```
  int main(void)
 {
    __HAL_UART_ENABLE_IT(&huart1,UART_IT_RXNE); //initialization of uart in stm32f4 hal library

  while (1)
  {

         if (Transfer_cplt==1)  //if buffer data succesfully transfered to un_decoded_data 
                         {

                    UnStuffData(un_decoded_data, 11,destination) ; //this is Consistive overhead algortim for decoding package. No problem with this one bc it uses global values

                                    predec_package=  make_predec_package(destination); //this function takes decoded data and makes some bit wise operations. and returns array of values with pointer. So i used malloc and after i am done with it i have to free it (below)
                                    free(destination); // this one is problem. Even if not in the ISR still related to ISR so still causing problems. 
                                    for( int i=0; i < 6; i++ ){
                                            decoded_data[i]=     *( predec_package + i ) ;

                                        }
                       }
    }}
```

Just in case i am adding the function which returns array and make problems. Here it is :

```
int16_t* make_predec_package( unsigned char *ptr){  //function takes array as input

int8_t n;
uint8_t temp_array[11] = {0};  //temporary array for calculations and also debugging 

int16_t  *temporary = calloc(8, sizeof(*temporary));  //temporary must be freed by caller


if(temporary)
{
     for( int i=0; i < 11; i++ ){
        temp_array[i]        =   *( ptr + i );
     }

     n = temp_array[0];

     //here some bitwise calculations...
    temporary[0] = (temp_array[1]*256 ) + temp_array[2]/4  ;
    temporary[1] = (temp_array[3]*256 )+ temp_array[4]/ 4  ;
    temporary[2]= temp_array[5];
    temporary[3]= temp_array[6];
    temporary[4]= temp_array[7];
    temporary[5]= temp_array[8];
    temporary[6]= temp_array[9];
    temporary[7]= temp_array[10];
}

     // i am returning fully decoded data array with pointer. 
return temporary;  
 }
```

Comment: "Since i am returning an array ,i had to use malloc" What?? That doesn't make the slightest sense.

Comment: @Ludin  I had to return array from a function.Thats why i need memory alllocation

Comment: No that's nonsense. You might as well return a pointer to memory allocated elsewhere, as long as it isn't allocated to the stack. Or preferably, pass the pointer as parameter and let the caller do the allocation. This is a microcontroller, not a PC, there is no need for dynamic allocation _anywhere_.

Comment: Can you please show me an example for that.That sounds helpfull.

Comment: @Lundin can you elaborate please? Right now i am using DMA , but still using free() corrupts my code. I want to learn how to avoid using malloc and free  in embeded platforms.

Comment: Just allocate as much memory as you need statically. [See this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/171257/realloc-wasting-lots-of-space-in-my-mcu/171581#171581)

Comment: @Lundin i do understand better now thank you. But why did my code work with malloc ? and not worked without malloc? (earlier version of my code  worked in main loop with malloc -no interrupt-  and not worked without malloc)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this code is fairly naive and should be rewritten from scratch.

You should minimize an ISR as much as possible, and it should not contain any application logic. Upon receiving data from an UART, the ISR should just place that data in a buffer. The preferred way to do this is not to use interrupts at all, but instead DMA.

If you don't have DMA on your MCU, then you have to come up with a ring buffer structure which will act as a FIFO from the ISR to the application. You need some manner of protection during reads, to ensure that the ISR doesn't write to the buffer while you read (race condition).

Since UART is most often quite slow, it might be enough to simply disable interrupts during the read, if your code fetching data from the buffer is faster than the time it takes to clock in 1+8+1 bits on the UART.

And then it might also be a good idea to use a minimum of program design, separating the UART driver entirely from the application logic.

Comment: Thank you for this , i will revise my codding immdiately.Can you eleborate which parts need to rewritten becauuse "naive". ISR will just read data and send it to buffer. In the main loop i will form a package from buffer values. And after that i will try it DMA because thats the correct way .

Comment: @EnesKuz Which ARM is this for? A lot of them have DMA. Which is kind of tricky to set up but once done, it does wonders for program performance. Interrupts should be avoided if possible, they are almost always a source of bugs and problems.

Comment: Arm Cortex M4 , Stm32f407 ,  i agree about wonders part but learning is really painfull if you start from Arduino

Answer (score -1):

I wasnt able to understand what went wrong with free(); function.
Howaver i advise you to get our output also as a pointer parametter.
exp:

```
make_predec_package(destination, predec_package);
```

instead of

```
predec_package=  make_predec_package(destination);
```

returning pointers always couse problems as i know.

and inside of the function respected to that change

```
void make_predec_package( unsigned char *ptr, int16_t* predec_package){  //function takes array as input

int8_t n;
uint8_t temp_array[11] = {0};  //temporary array for calculations and also debugging 

//int16_t  *temporary = calloc(8, sizeof(*temporary)); 

     for( int i=0; i < 11; i++ ){
     temp_array[i]        =   *( ptr + i );
     }

 n = temp_array[0];

 //here some bitwise calculations...
predec_package[0] = (temp_array[1]*256 ) + temp_array[2]/4  ;
predec_package[1] = (temp_array[3]*256 )+ temp_array[4]/ 4  ;
predec_package[2]= temp_array[5];
predec_package[3]= temp_array[6];
predec_package[4]= temp_array[7];
predec_package[5]= temp_array[8];
predec_package[6]= temp_array[9];
predec_package[7]= temp_array[10];
}

 // i am returning fully decoded data array with pointer. 
 //return temporary;  
 }
```

only i couldnt see where did u declarate "predec_package" so make sure the lenght of array right(8<).

Comment: "I wasnt able to understand what went wrong with free(); function" Then you probably shouldn't be answering this. It is an embedded system microcontroller. Using `free` 1) doesn't make sense in the first place, and 2) especially doesn't make any sense inside an ISR. This question isn't an algorithm problem, but a complete misunderstanding of how to write ISRs.

Comment: Thank you @ugur.I was avoiding returning pointers for a year but i thought i was time i learn all about it since many functions i wrote requires it. About your edit :I dont want to define globals in sake of incapsulation.